# DB2 Transaction log is full. How to flush / clear it?

Tags: db2, amazon-ec2, flush, transaction-log

I’m working on a experiment regarding to a course I’m taking about tuning DB2. I’m using the EC2 from Amazon (aws) to conduct the experiment.

My problem is, however, that I have to test a non-compression against row-compression in DB2 and to do that I’ve created a bsh file that run those experiments. But when I reach to my compression part I get the error ”**Transaction log is full**”; and no matter how low I set the inserts for it is complaining about my transaction log.

I’ve scouted Google for a day now trying to find some way to flush / clear the log or just get rit of it, i don’t need it. I’ve tried to increase the size but nothing has helped.

Please, I hope someone has an answer to solve this frustrating problem

Thanks
- Mestika

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to "clear the log" in DB2.  When a transaction is rolled back, DB2 releases the log space used by the transaction.

If you've increased the log size and it has not helped, please post more information about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

No need of restarting.  Just try to force the applications using DB2 force applications all.

Increase the Actie Log File Size and try to force application connections and terminate the connections.

Try to run the job now.

```
db2 force applications all 

db2 update db cfg for sample using logfilsiz 5125

db2 force applications all

db2 terminate

db2 connect to sample
```

Run your job and monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Just restart the instance, it would release the pending logs and you should be fine